# Next.js build fail because "slug" was not provided as string

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js, typeerror

I'm trying to create a blog using Next.js and typescript, I'm having a problem with [slug].tsx, I keep getting the following error:

> Build error occurred Error: A required parameter (slug) was not provided as a string in getStaticPaths for /blog/[slug]

I mainly following this tutorial, this is the exact timestamp:
https://youtu.be/jJF6oBw1lbo?t=582

I was successful in following the tutorial in Typescript instead of javascript until I got to this part, now I can't perform the build.

When I try to run "yarn run dev", I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'tap' of undefined

This is my code for [slug].tsx:

```
import { GetStaticPaths, GetStaticProps } from 'next'

let client = require('contentful').createClient({
    space: process.env.CONTENTFUL_SPACE_ID,
    accessToken: process.env.CONTENTFUL_ACCESS_TOKEN,
})

type Params = {
    params: {
        slug: string
    }
}

export const getStaticPaths: GetStaticPaths = async () => {
    let data = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'article',
    });
    return {
        paths: data.items.map(item => ({
            params: {slug: item.fields.slug},
        })),
        fallback: true,
    }
}

export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
    let data = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'article',
        'fields.slug': params.slug
    })
    return {
        props: {
            article: data.items[0]
        }
    }
}

export default function Article({ article }) {

    return <article>
        <h1>{article.fields.title}</h1>
        {article.fields.content}
    </article>

}
```

Does the problem have to do with the slug data type? should I explicitly declare it as a string? and how do I do it?

Comment: For the first error, ensure that `item.fields.slug` is not returning `undefined` before setting it as a path.

Comment: @juliomalves how would I test this?

Answer (score 0):

NextJS `getStaticPaths` expects that each property on the `params` object will be a string. You can see where NextJS throws this error in the [source code](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/5b9ad8da909a7870280c39340c189392d6307994/packages/next/build/utils.ts#L689).

You've also got that `slug` type correctly defined (but unused?) here:

```
type Params = {
    params: {
        slug: string
    }
}
```

In the `getStaticPaths` return statement, you're mapping over data from Contentful:

```
params: {slug: item.fields.slug},
```

So you'll firstly need to ensure you are returning a string for that `params.slug` property. This field should have validation and be required as a `string` in your Contentful content model.

You will also want to defend against that `item.fields.slug` returning `undefined`. In my experience, this can happen in Contentful when drafts are auto-saved with empty required fields.

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) to defensively short-circuit the expression if any reference in the chain is invalid sometimes is useful i.e. `item?.fields?.slug` but that's probably not needed here, so try a simple OR logical operator.

This can probably be written more succinctly but something like this should work in the body of your `getStaticPaths` function:

```
const paths = data.items.reduce((pagePaths, item) => {
  const slug = item.fields.slug || '';

  if (slug.length > 0) {
    pagePaths.push({
      params: { slug },
    });
  }

  return pagePaths;
}, []);

return {
  paths,
  fallback: false,
};
```